# One session per tab in JSF 1.2

Tags: jsf, session, web-applications, browser-tab

I am working on a JSF 1.2 application. Consider the following use case with a browser with 2 tabs:

1. In the first tab I login with user 'TEST'.
2. In the second tab I login with user 'TEST2'.
3. When I return back to the first tab, the logged-in user is changed to 'TEST2'.

How can I restrict the login to the current tab instead of all tabs? In other words, how can I restrict the HTTP session to one tab instead of all tabs of the browser instance?

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Don't you mean per _tab_?

Comment: I am using firefox.. I need per user per tab

Comment: Is this requirement for develoment or production purposes? The answers posted so far assume development purposes.

Comment: i need for production purpose..

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the **Private Tab**. This will do the trick.

The private tab **does not hold cookies**. So it's a new session cookie for each tab.

***NEW:***

**Another approach is disabling the cookies for your browser.**

- The default JSF behavior is concatenating the JSESSIONID in the URL.
  So each tab will have a different JSESSIONID as a URL parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use 2 different browsers (like chrome and firefox)

If you're using FireFox install the [MultiFox](http://br.mozdev.org/multifox/) plugin